# Getting wrong response from date through awk

Tags: linux, awk, date

I am trying to create a script that can transform an output from a Cisco switch showing last input and output on an interface to a useful format. This is to be able to know what interfaces hasn't been used, let's say, the last 6 months. Cisco just says that an interfaces last input was `10w4d`.

What I have come to so far is an input-file like this:

```
FastEthernet0/4,3 days ago,3 days ago
FastEthernet0/8,46 years ago ,46 years ago 
FastEthernet0/10,46 years ago ,46 years ago 
FastEthernet0/11,46 years ago ,46 years ago 
FastEthernet0/12,08:47:53,04:00:32
FastEthernet0/13,1 year ago 46 weeks ago ,1 year ago 46 weeks ago 
FastEthernet0/14,46 years ago ,46 years ago 
FastEthernet0/15,13 weeks ago 4 days ago ,13 weeks ago 4 days ago 
FastEthernet0/16,46 years ago ,46 years ago 
FastEthernet0/18,46 years ago ,46 years ago 
FastEthernet0/19,46 years ago ,46 years ago 
FastEthernet0/20,46 years ago ,46 years ago 
FastEthernet0/22,46 years ago ,1 year ago 50 weeks ago 
FastEthernet0/24,46 years ago ,46 years ago
```

I have set all interfaces that has the status of never on last input and output to 46 years ago, so I can get a valid date. And yes, I do have a record of uptime to be able to take that into account.

My issue now is that I am trying to convert that into a valid date. Doing that through `awk` and `xargs` works fine, if I do like this:

```
awk -F, '{print $2}' tst | xargs -i date -d "{}" +%Y-%m-%d
```

I get a response like this:

```
2016-08-18
1970-08-21
1970-08-21
1970-08-21
2016-08-21
2014-10-03
1970-08-21
2016-05-18
1970-08-21
1970-08-21
1970-08-21
1970-08-21
1970-08-21
1970-08-21
```

But if I do like this, which in my mind should give the same result:

```
awk -F, -v OFS="," '{
    cmd2=("date \"+'%Y-%m-%d'\" -d \""$2 "\"")
    cmd2|getline d2
    print cmd2,d2
}' tst
```

I get a response like this:

```
date "+%Y-%m-%d" -d "3 days ago",2016-08-18
date "+%Y-%m-%d" -d "46 years ago ",1970-08-21
date "+%Y-%m-%d" -d "46 years ago ",1970-08-21
date "+%Y-%m-%d" -d "46 years ago ",1970-08-21
date "+%Y-%m-%d" -d "08:47:53",2016-08-21
date "+%Y-%m-%d" -d "1 year ago 46 weeks ago ",2014-10-03
date "+%Y-%m-%d" -d "46 years ago ",2014-10-03
date "+%Y-%m-%d" -d "13 weeks ago 4 days ago ",2016-05-18
date "+%Y-%m-%d" -d "46 years ago ",2016-05-18
date "+%Y-%m-%d" -d "46 years ago ",2016-05-18
date "+%Y-%m-%d" -d "46 years ago ",2016-05-18
date "+%Y-%m-%d" -d "46 years ago ",2016-05-18
date "+%Y-%m-%d" -d "46 years ago ",2016-05-18
date "+%Y-%m-%d" -d "46 years ago ",2016-05-18
```

I added the `cmd2` to the `print` command just now to see what it was trying to do. Just running that command gives me the correct date.

I guess I have missed something simple, but after trying over and over again for 3-4 hours now I would like to have another set of eyes on it.

Anybody out there that can point me in the right direction?

**Updated! With just three lines of the input-file I wasn't getting any issues myself, as Stephen also pointed out. Sorry for posting an untested scenario.**

Comment: I get the right results on my machine...
`date "+%Y-%m-%d" -d "1 year ago 46 weeks ago ",2014-10-03
date "+%Y-%m-%d" -d "46 years ago ",1970-08-21
date "+%Y-%m-%d" -d "13 weeks ago 4 days ago ",2016-05-18`

Comment: `awk -F, '{system("date +%F -d \""$2"\"")}' tst`

Comment: With just those three lines of the input file I didn't get errors myself either. Updated with more data to work with

Comment: `cut -d, -f2 tst | date -I -f -`

Comment: Costas, your system call solution works fine it seems, I do get all the dates correctly. Can I store the output from the systemcall to a variable? What I would like to do is to replace the relative dates in column 2 and 3 with real dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do:

```
cmd = "some command"
cmd | getline d2
cmd | getline d2
```

in `awk`, the first `getline` gets the first line (record) of the output of `cmd` (`cmd` is then started upon that first `getline`), and the second one gets the second line. Upon reaching the end of the output, `getline` returns 0.

In your case of `cmd = "date -d \"46 years ago\""`, since that command only outputs one line, the first `getline` returns that line in `d2` (and a positive number), but the second reaches `eof`, so returns 0 and leaves `d2` untouched.

Here, you'd need:

```
 cmd | getline d2; close(cmd)
```

So `cmd` be run each time.

Or store the output of `cmd` in a hash to avoid running the same command several times with the same arguments, like

```
if (!($2 in cache)) {cmd=...; cmd | getline cache[$2]; close(cmd)}
print cache[$2]
```

It's still a good idea to close `cmd` there to avoid leaving a great number of file descriptors open.

---

Note the ambiguity in `close(cmd)` when `cmd` is used both for `getline < cmd` and `cmd | getline`. Does it close the `cmd` *command* or the `cmd` *file* or both?

```
$ cat test.awk
BEGIN{
  OFS=","
  getline a1 < "uname"
  "uname" | getline b1
  close("uname")

  getline a2 < "uname"
  "uname" | getline b2
  print a1,b1,a2,b2
}
$ echo test > uname
$ mawk -f test.awk
test,Linux,test,Linux
$ bwk-awk -f test.awk
test,Linux,test,Linux
$ gawk -f test.awk
test,Linux,,Linux
$ busybox awk -f test.awk
test,,test,
```

(`bwk-awk` being the one maintained by Brian Kernighan (the `k` in `awk`), the behaviour is similar with awk implementations based on that like Solaris `nawk` or FreeBSD `awk`).

See how busybox awk doesn't let you use `"uname"` as both a file and command with `getline` and how `close("uname")` doesn't close the `uname` *file* in `gawk`.

So, it's a good idea to make sure you don't use a file and command with the same name at the same time. You can add a `"\n"` at the beginning or end of a *command* to make it unlikely that it be confused with a *file*.

Like:

```
 awk 'BEGIN {getline foo < $ENVIRON["FILE"]; "uname\n" | getline system}'
```

would avoid the problem if `$FILE` happens to be `uname` (not if `$FILE` is `uname<newline>` but that's less likely).

Answer (score 2):

So this is interesting; it seems in this structure `awk` is remembering that it's made this call before and not doing it again, and so not passing any data to `readline`.

We can see this by doing `strace -f -o xxx awk ....`

Looking through the trace we see:

```
3401  execve("/bin/date", ["date", "+%Y-%m-%d", "-d", "3 days ago"], [/* 50 vars */]) = 0
3403  execve("/bin/date", ["date", "+%Y-%m-%d", "-d", "46 years ago "], [/* 50 vars */]) = 0
3405  execve("/bin/date", ["date", "+%Y-%m-%d", "-d", "08:47:53"], [/* 50 vars */]) = 0
3407  execve("/bin/date", ["date", "+%Y-%m-%d", "-d", "1 year ago 46 weeks ago "], [/* 50 vars */]) = 0
3409  execve("/bin/date", ["date", "+%Y-%m-%d", "-d", "13 weeks ago 4 days ago "], [/* 50 vars */]) = 0
```

So each unique date is passed once, but never again.  This happens with GNU awk on CentOS 7 and `mawk` on Debian, so this seems to be expected behaviour.

A simple hack is to make each line unique; eg add a comment with the line number.

```
cmd2="date \"+'%Y-%m-%d'\" -d \""$2 "\" ; # " NR
```

The resulting code looks something like:

```
awk -F, -v OFS="," '{cmd2="date \"+'%Y-%m-%d'\" -d \""$2 "\" ; # " NR ;
                     cmd2|getline d2;
                     print cmd2,d2}' x
date "+%Y-%m-%d" -d "3 days ago" ; # 1,2016-08-18
date "+%Y-%m-%d" -d "46 years ago " ; # 2,1970-08-21
date "+%Y-%m-%d" -d "46 years ago " ; # 3,1970-08-21
date "+%Y-%m-%d" -d "46 years ago " ; # 4,1970-08-21
date "+%Y-%m-%d" -d "08:47:53" ; # 5,2016-08-21
date "+%Y-%m-%d" -d "1 year ago 46 weeks ago " ; # 6,2014-10-03
date "+%Y-%m-%d" -d "46 years ago " ; # 7,1970-08-21
date "+%Y-%m-%d" -d "13 weeks ago 4 days ago " ; # 8,2016-05-18
date "+%Y-%m-%d" -d "46 years ago " ; # 9,1970-08-21
date "+%Y-%m-%d" -d "46 years ago " ; # 10,1970-08-21
date "+%Y-%m-%d" -d "46 years ago " ; # 11,1970-08-21
date "+%Y-%m-%d" -d "46 years ago " ; # 12,1970-08-21
date "+%Y-%m-%d" -d "46 years ago " ; # 13,1970-08-21
date "+%Y-%m-%d" -d "46 years ago " ; # 14,1970-08-21
```

A more complicated solution would be to cache results in an array and only call `date` if you haven't seen this date before.

Comment: Thanks for the troubleshooting Stephen, no wonder I didn't get it working. This helped me getting the information I needed, and can continue my project. For the record I am using Ubuntu 16.04.1 and running Gnu AWK version 4.1.3.

Comment: It's just that you need to do a `close(cmd)`, otherwise, `cmd|getline` keeps reading remainder lines in the output of `cmd` (here eof after the first line as there's only one line). That's standard and expected behaviour of `awk`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I learned something today :-)  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To replace the relative dates in column 2 and 3 with real dates

```
awk -F, '{for(i=2;i<4;i++){"date -I -d \""$i"\"" | getline a; $i=a}}1' OFS=, tst
```

I was suprised that direct `getline $i` didn't work: it change either one field of two or nothing. So I have to include additional variable `a`
With user function defined:

```
awk -F, '
    function cmd2(date){
        "date -I -d \""date"\"" | getline a
        return a
    }
    {
        $2=cmd2($2)
        $3=cmd2($3)
        print
    }' OFS=, tst
```

But if the function is defined with local variable `cmd2(date,   a)` it show the same behavior as noted above.

For homogenous lines task can be easy done with **GNU sed**

```
tr ',' '\n' tst |
sed '1~3!{s/^/date -I -d "/;s/$/"/e;}' |
paste -sd ',,\n'
```